# How AWS lambda stores the state for checkpoint dynamo db streams

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Recently working with AWS lambda with dynamo DB stream event source,  I noticed 25000 RCUs consumed within 1 day. I am sure of not running queries or scans that might have consumed 25000 RCUs.

I suspect that internally like kinesis there is some checkpointing done to capture the state. But could not find any conclusive documentation.  Has someone come across something similar.

Comment: In dynamoDB streams it could be IteratorAge too(same in kinesis). "For stream-based invocations, Lambda emits the IteratorAge metric. Iterator age is the time between when the last record in a batch was recorded and when Lambda reads the record"

Comment: Enable CloudTrail and you should be able to see